# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (undefined:1) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, undefined

I'm working with a local JSON file with multiple different programs. Periodically these programs also rewrite the file and read from it. This all works out fine, but I get this error after some time (it's random when I get it):

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/desktop/test.js:273:25)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:535:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:479:7)
```

It points to this line of code:

```
var variable = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test.json', 'utf8'));
```

My guess is that one of the programs tries to read from the JSON file right as the other one is re-writing it (JSON file is around 3MB) but I could be wrong. If this is the case, let me hear your ideas on how I could check if the JSON file is being saved before reading form it and if this isn't the problem what elese could be causing it.

Comment: Old, very likely out of date, but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849427/node-js-readfile-race-condition-reading-file-when-not-fully-written-to-disk

Comment: `I'm working with a local JSON file with multiple different programs` - Say no more, this can only lead to terrible things. I once tried to run with JSON storage for a growing application and it only lead to numerous instances of data loss/corruption and much sadness - and that was only one program, multiple programs is guaranteed disaster. Use a proper data storage solution, like some SQL or noSQL or some AWS service

Comment: And yes, it is most likely due to the situation you describe. Also possible is a program crashing while writing (causing the json to corrupt or be empty), topping out on allocated memory, etc.

Comment: Ah, I'd really hate to have an SQL server or something similar as I'm only using small apps that only gather some basic data from an API and process it for myself only.